# Ultragrid child rows

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, ultrawingrid

I want to be able to display child rows upon load. Right now I have it to where you have to click around all of the rows to see which ones have child rows. I want to be able to display child rows if their are child rows. I am a complete ultragrid beginner so can somebody with some experience guid me into a general direction? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try the following code in order to get indication ONLY if you have child rows:

```
    private void ultraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Layout.Override.ExpansionIndicator = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ShowExpansionIndicator.CheckOnDisplay;
    }
```

And if you want these rows to be expanded on load, you could use this code sample:

```
ultraGrid1.Rows.ExpandAll(true);
```